# Caracteres especiales, espacios, acentos y XSS en registro PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema que me deja vulnerable a la hora de registrar usuarios nuevos en mi base de datos queria saber esto:
1. Scripts en registro, 2. Acentos en registro, 3. Caracteres especiales, 4. Espacios en nombre

```
1. <script>alert("alerta")</script>

2. ñàó

3. )(/&%$·"!ª[]{}-_,`^

4. hola k ase
```

Por si es necesario estoy creando el sistema en MySQLi orientado a objetos.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el código que utilizas?

Comment: +1 por hola k ase. aunque personalmente prefiero ola k ase. No queda muy claro lo que ya tienes, Jorge. Añade más información por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Para prevenir un ataque XSS (Cross Site Scripting) se pueden filtrar los datos con `htmlspecialcharts`

Si obtenemos los datos mediante `$_GET`, `$_POST` debemos filtrar siempre los datos antes de agregarlos a la base de datos.

Si hay diferentes fuentes de introducción de datos, la mejor forma es a la hora de mostrar los datos, filtrar antes de ser impresos.

Ejemplo de un ataque XSS

```
//Test Ataque XSS 
$str='<script>alert("hacked")</script>';

//Sin protección XSS
echo $str;

//Protección XSS - Cross Stie Scripting
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Cómo puedes observar con `echo $str` en el navegador saltará un cuadro de mensaje con el texto "hacked", para prevenir eso, usar `htmlspecialchars...`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la funcion "htmlspecialcharts" de php para evitar inyecciones de codigo! eso te puede servir al registrar usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-site scripting o XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) en un conjunto de vulnerabilidades que afectan a navegadores, basados en scripts en el lado del cliente; **NO** pueden afectar directamente a tu base de datos (sea Mysql u otra).

Pero si permites que los clientes guarden scripts en tus tablas sí puede ser conveniente que limpies lo que devuelves desde Mysql/PHP al navegador del cliente controlando qué es o no permisible.

Podrías, por ejemplo cambiar con una expresión regular todo tag `<script>` para impedir que se ejecute en el navegador del cliente.